# Use number style with natbib (author-year style) for beamer citation in rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer, bibtex

In default, `\usepackage{natbib}` uses the *author-year* style for citation, while we can set `\setcitestyle{numbers}` to use the *number* style in References: i.e., the *author-year* style for the main body of the text and the *number* style for references. My **pure-latex-beamer** toy example (`test-pure.tex`) is given follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib}\setcitestyle{round}
\usepackage{hyperref}\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Packages}
\begin{itemize}
\item knitr \citet{knitr2015}
\item ggplot2 \citet{ggplot22016}
\item purrr \citet{R-purrr}
\item tibble \citet{R-tibble}
\item tidyr \citet{R-tidyr}
\item usethis \citet{R-usethis}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\setcitestyle{numbers} %%%comment this to show (default) author-year style
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{pkg.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

where `pkg.bib` is

```
@Book{knitr2015,
  title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2015},
  edition = {2nd},
  note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url = {https://yihui.org/knitr/},
}

@Book{ggplot22016,
  author = {Hadley Wickham},
  title = {ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag New York},
  year = {2016},
  isbn = {978-3-319-24277-4},
  url = {https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org},
}

@Manual{R-purrr,
  title = {purrr: Functional Programming Tools},
  author = {Lionel Henry and Hadley Wickham},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 0.3.4},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=purrr},
}

@Manual{R-tibble,
  title = {tibble: Simple Data Frames},
  author = {Kirill Müller and Hadley Wickham},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 3.0.3},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tibble},
}

@Manual{R-tidyr,
  title = {tidyr: Tidy Messy Data},
  author = {Hadley Wickham and Lionel Henry},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 1.1.0},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyr},
}

@Manual{R-usethis,
  title = {usethis: Automate Package and Project Setup},
  author = {Hadley Wickham and Jennifer Bryan},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 1.6.1},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=usethis},
}
```

One can test that the `test-pure.tex` run successfully and well. Now, I want to reproduce `test-pure.tex` to use the **rmarkdown-beamer** (`test.rmd`), and I try

````
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{natbib}\setcitestyle{round}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
---

## Packages

- knitr @knitr2015
- ggplot2 @ggplot22016
- purrr @R-purrr
- tibble @R-tibble
- tidyr @R-tidyr
- usethis @R-usethis

## References {.allowframebreaks}

```{=latex}
\setcitestyle{numbers}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{pkg.bib}
```
````

where the `{=latex}` command is hinted from Section 6.11 of [rmarkdown-cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html).

However, although `test.rmd` can run without errors, there are nothing to show in the References! Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating a bibliography in Rmarkdown, you don't need to use `\bibliography` explicitly, it is created automatically if you provide a `.bib` file in `bibliography` yaml key in yaml frontmatter.

Now to use the author-year style for the main body of the text and the number style for references with `natbib`, we can use [this answer from Tex StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544257/261065).

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: natbib
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
bibliography: pkg.bib
citecolor: LimeGreen
urlcolor: Magenta
link-citations: true
link-bibliography: true
natbiboptions: round
biblio-style: unsrtnat
---


## Packages

- knitr [@knitr2015]
- ggplot2 [@ggplot22016]
- purrr [@R-purrr]
- tibble [@R-tibble]
- tidyr [@R-tidyr]
- usethis [@R-usethis]


# References
```

**preamble.tex**

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\@biblabel\NAT@biblabelnum
  \let\@bibsetup\NAT@bibsetnum}
\makeatother
```

---

[image: author-year citation style with numeric biblio style in natbib]

---

As an alternative, we can also use `biblatex`. Because `biblatex` provides options to set citestyle as `authoryear` and bibstyle as `numeric`.

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: pkg.bib
citecolor: LimeGreen
urlcolor: Magenta
link-citations: true
link-bibliography: true
biblatexoptions:
  - citestyle = authoryear
  - bibstyle = numeric
---

## Packages

- knitr [@knitr2015]
- ggplot2 [@ggplot22016]
- purrr [@R-purrr]
- tibble [@R-tibble]
- tidyr [@R-tidyr]
- usethis [@R-usethis]


# References
```

---

[image: author-year citation style with numeric biblio style in biblatex]

---

Comment: Two splendid approaches!!!@shafee